# delays in receiving and processing BTS message

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a strange problem , I receive messages using http receive dll on IIS virtual directory and it does not start processing on orchestration until 2 or more minutes after it is received i'm using custom pipeline and BizTalk 2009, so anyone can help me please.

---

i found out that what happened is that BizTalk host increase memory usage incrementally until it reach something like 1,3 GB then it raise memory over follow exception and i should restart all host instances to get back to work

Comment: How is your environment behave generally? do you see a similar delay using, say, the file adpater?

Comment: What is the size of the data?  Using tracked message data, how long does it take the data to traverse the pipeline?

Comment: after those two questions, I'd ask what the custom pipeline does

Comment: And after the pipeline+pipeline components comes.... Maps.

Are you using maps? and what is the thresshold setting for "large maps"? (streaming versus DOM XSLT)

Comment: Before the memory overflow, BTS will likely start throttling. [Some ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569162/forcing-a-biztalk-host-to-throttle-for-debugging-purposes/20585655#20585655)