# Forcing a Biztalk Host to Throttle for Debugging Purposes

Tags: biztalk

we're currently having issue in our production servers and would like to try to replicate the issue in our dev. I'm currently awaiting access to our Performance Monitoring Tool, and while waiting would like to play with it a little.

I'm thinking of, since I suspect a host throttling in prod, forcing hosts to throttle in dev and see if it will recreate the issue.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Once you know what the throttling is (when you get access to perfmon), it might be possible to simulate it either with load or by reduction in config setting to force a throttle. Is this BizTalk 2010?

Comment: Why the Q. vote down I wonder ....?

Comment: @Jason, I'm wondering the same thing, too.

Comment: +1 because it might lead to an interesting exploration of throttling :)

Comment: I'm curious about it, too. Especially now that I'm only starting to learn about BizTalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, monitoring of the [throttling counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559893.aspx) and other counters like [memory and WIP messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561922.aspx) is a must to see what is going on in your production server. Also would recommend that set up a SCOM alert on throttling states of 3+ (publishing + delivery states), if you have SCOM.

Message throughput can grind to a halt on especially the memory (4, 5) and Queue Size (6) states. States 1+2 are generally short lived (e.g. arrival of a large batch of messages) and Biztalk recovers within a few seconds.

Simulating the memory state in your Dev environment should be straightforward by tweaking the [throttling thresholds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559628%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) (obviously not something to be taken lightly in production!)

e.g. to trigger the Memory threshold states - AFAIK the lowest memory usage threshold [you can set is 101MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559628%28v=bts.20%29.aspx). Running a load test in dev should then be able reproduce the throttle.
There is also apparantly a user-based throttling override to set states [10 and 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx) although haven't actually tried this.

Some other experience on avoiding throttling:

(Caveat - I don't have an active BizTalk 2006/R2 setup - this is for 2009 / 2010)

- If you do a lot of asynchronous processing (e.g. Queue receives), ensure that you have split functionality into separate [Hosts for Receive, Processing and Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296645%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) hosts. This way you can adjust the throttling for asynch Receive hosts to trigger much earlier than the processing and sending hosts - this should have the effect of constricting new incoming messages to the messagebox but allowing existing messages to complete processing.
- On 64 bit hosts, the default 25% memory host usage throttling level is usually an unnecessary liability - [we increased this using Yossi Dahan's recommendation of 50% on a 4GB server](http://blog.sabratech.co.uk/2008/04/throttling-in-full-action.html)
- Note that suspended messages count toward throttling state 6 - ensure that you have a strategy for dealing with suspended messages (and obviously ensure that the Sql Agent jobs are running!).

Comment: +1 for the mention of suspended messages counting in the throttle count - I've seen this trip up a few clients in the past.

Comment: Thank you. I will be doing your suggestion and inform you guys if it works.

Comment: We finally got access to PerMon and saw that Message Publishing was in throttling state 6. We didn't have to force our dev server to throttle because of this. Thank you all for your help!